# How to group pandas dataframe by unique combination of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like below:

```
To    From    Price
NY    CA      2000
NY    MI      4000
CA    NY      3000
NY    CA      3000
```

How can I efficiently get (and store) separate data frames for each unique combination of To and From? The end goal is to make graphs using the data frames thus formed. Any alternative(and more efficient) method is also welcome.

Example:

DF 1:

```
To    From    Price
NY    CA      2000
NY    CA      3000
```

DF 2:

```
To    From    Price
NY    MI      4000
```

DF 3:

```
To    From    Price
CA    NY      3000
```

Comment: `data.groupby(['To', 'From'])` ?

Comment: pandas supports groupby operations for many plots. Maybe you don't need to have three separate DataFrames but just a `groupby().plot()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply a `df.groupby` operation on `To` and `From` and iterate over each group.

```
In [749]: df_list = [g for _, g in df.groupby(['To', 'From'])]

In [750]: for d in df_list:
     ...:     print(d)
     ...:     print('-' * 20)
     ...:     
   To From  Price
2  CA   NY   3000
--------------------
   To From  Price
0  NY   CA   2000
3  NY   CA   3000
--------------------
   To From  Price
1  NY   MI   4000
--------------------
```

Each element in `df_list` is a dataframe.

---

A [word of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792000/how-to-group-pandas-data-frame-by-unique-combination-of-two-columns/45792062#comment78541845_45792000) is to not break up these groups unless you really need to.